# Best unit testing framework for Clojure?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

What is the best unit testing framework for Clojure?

I prefer a more BDD style framework.

Answer (score 23):

I wrote clojure.test, and I am working on a new framework, [lazytest](http://github.com/stuartsierra/lazytest), with a more functional style.

Comment: Can't wait to do QuickCheck-style testing in Clojure with lazytest! Thanks a lot for all your contributions.

Comment: Is there any way to integrate lazytest with Intellij IDEA? Something like the [Infinitest plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3146)?

Comment: Probably not very up-to-date myself, but I see a big ** Not under development** banner on github. Probably midje now is one of the best choices for tdd.

Answer (score 23):

I'm working on a mock-oriented, top-down testing framework. It'll have three levels of abstraction. The first two are finished:

http://github.com/marick/Midje#readme

I'm working on the top level, which will look something like this:

http://www.exampler.com/blog/2010/06/10/tdd-in-clojure-a-sketch-part-1/

Also, see my answer at this stackoverflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417239/47630

Answer (score 6):

Stuart Halloway, author of the [Programming Clojure](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/programming-clojure) book, is currently working on [Circumspec](http://github.com/stuarthalloway/circumspec), advertised as "BDD in Clojure" in the README. This is a work in progress, but perhaps may be what you're looking for. There's also [Conducta](http://code.google.com/p/conducta/), which is apparently meant to enable BDD in Clojure with [some funny syntax](http://stoto79.blogspot.com/2008/11/clojure-meets-bdd.html).

*(Updated this paragraph in response to Stuart Sierra's comment below.)* Out of the box, Clojure provides `clojure.test` and `clojure.test.junit` namespaces. The former is a Clojure specific framework, while the latter generates JUnit-style XML reports based on `clojure.test`'s output. There's a successor to `clojure.test` in the works currently, but it's very usable as it stands now.

Finally, since I understand (from your previous question) that you're just starting out with the language, I'll add that if there's some testing framework you especially like and it's available on the JVM, there's a good chance that writing a wrapper in Clojure may not be too much of a problem. Or you can just write "Java in Clojure" and use Javaish idioms directly with no wrappers at all. Clojure's Java interop is excellent.

Comment: Correction: clojure.test.junit only generates JUnit-style XML reports from clojure.test; it is not a JUnit integration library.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Stuart! I'll edit the answer straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I created one when learning Clojure.

http://bitbucket.org/Kunjan_Kshetri/clojure_unit/src/cabab38ca3e6/unittest.clj

Answer (score 0):

I think nowadays (2022)
https://github.com/lambdaisland/kaocha should be checked out. It is a very powerful testing lib.