# Strengths of Clojure testing frameworks?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure

Which one do you prefer and why? What are the pros and cons of each? In which scenario does each outshine the others?

I'm particularly interested in midje vs. clojure.test, but feel free to bring up other Clojure testing frameworks too.

See also [Best unit testing framework for Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444960/best-unit-testing-framework-for-clojure) (the answers to that question didn't provide much detail on the "why").

Comment: In a similar vein, how are folks parallelizing their test runs? None of the frameworks seem immediately amenable to running thousands of tests in parallel and gathering results in a tidy fashion at the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best unit testing framework for Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444960/best-unit-testing-framework-for-clojure)

Comment: hey @andy Great question.  Midje won't do parallel test runs either and I wonder if there is a way it could be tweaked to enable parallels.  I'm going to open an issue: https://github.com/marick/Midje/issues/108

Answer (score 11):

I haven't tried them all, but I like plain old [clojure.test](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.test-api.html) for the following reasons:

- **It's already there in the Clojure API**: No extra dependencies.
- **Integrates well with Maven**: I use Eclipse with the clojure-maven-plugin to ensure that both Clojure and Java tests get run automatically whenever I build.
- **It's simple**: 99% of what I need in testing is just to be able to write a well structured set of assertions, clojure.test makes that pretty easy

Sample code:

```
(testing "Arithmetic"
  (testing "with positive integers"
    (is (= 4 (+ 2 2)))
    (is (= 7 (+ 3 4))))
  (testing "with negative integers"
    (is (= -4 (+ -2 -2)))
    (is (= -1 (+ 3 -4)))))
```

Answer (score 11):

I prefer [Midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje). Midje provides a migration path from clojure.test to a more flexible, readable, abstract, and gracious style of testing.

Midje supports top-down as well as bottom-up TDD styles, and has mocking and stubbing facilities baked into it, as well as some powerful features like checkers, metaconstants, tabular facts.

[Midje wiki](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki)

Here's a simple example:

```
(fact "Midje can do simple stubbing"
  (+ (a) 2) => 5
  (provided 
    (a) => 3))
```

Comment: Midje also has excellent, comprehensive documentation, which is certainly an aspect that sets it apart from clojure.test.

Comment: Note that Midje executes tests when namespace is loaded! So you are in trouble when your tests are long-running or you want to use linters or other code analysis tools. And instead of untangling these two things which would ultimately simplify development it only has option to disable checks. Not nice.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer [expectations](https://github.com/jaycfields/expectations) or `clojure.test` with [humane-test-output](https://github.com/pjstadig/humane-test-output). Both options give the most readable errors and provide fairly minimal syntax.

### clojure.test example

Given the following test you get the following output below.

```
(deftest map-comparisons
  (is (= {:sheep 1} {:cheese 1 :sheep 1})))
```

#### Default clojure.test output

```
FAIL in (map-comparisons) (map_test.clj:5)
expected: (= {:sheep 1} {:cheese 1, :sheep 1})
  actual: (not (= {:sheep 1} {:cheese 1, :sheep 1}))
```

#### Example of clojure.test output with humane-test-output

```
FAIL in (map-comparisons) (map_test.clj:5)
expected: {:sheep 1}
  actual: {:cheese 1, :sheep 1}
    diff: + {:cheese 1}
```

## expectations example

The test looks like:

```
(expect {:sheep 1} {:sheep 1, :cheese 1})
```

#### expectations output

```
failure in (map_expectations.clj:6) : example.map-expectations
(expect {:sheep 1} {:sheep 1, :cheese 1})

           expected: {:sheep 1}
                was: {:cheese 1, :sheep 1}

           in expected, not actual: null
           in actual, not expected: {:cheese 1}
```

I did a more detailed comparison of output of the four main Clojure testing libraries and that can be found [here](http://jakemccrary.com/blog/2014/06/22/comparing-clojure-testing-libraries-output/).