# unit testing in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure and I'm trying to write my unit tests. What is the best way to write unit tests in Clojure and how do I import the file where my functions are defined to my unit test.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possibly similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444960/best-unit-testing-framework-for-clojure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start with, there's [clojure.test](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.test-api.html). Using [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen#readme), you can call `lein test` to run the tests.

See also [Speclj](https://github.com/slagyr/speclj) which is useful for BDD.

Answer (score 5):

Another accepted way to do unittest in clojure is using [Midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje).

I have read good comments about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Speclj](http://speclj.com/) is also a testing framework for the clojure language widely accepted that you may consider as well. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928250/how-do-midje-and-speclj-compare) you can find a longer discussion about it's strong-weak points